# How do I change the frequency on the cycle time report?

Tags: rally, cycle, kanban

We are using the KANBAN borad.  We would like to use the cycle time report but would like to reduce from months to weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is not possible. You may change a frequency to weeks using a separate Cycle/Lead Time, as screenshot shows.

[image]

This is a separate app, not related to Kanban, and also based on ScheduleState. The cycle time report in the Kanban app, available from the gear icon cannot be customized.